# GeckoFX 7.0, 8.0 and 9.0 on Linux crash very frequently

Tags: geckofx

I cloned GeckoFX 7.0, 8.0 and 9.0 from https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/ and use MonoDevelop 2.6 to build and debug it.

I only change xulrunner path in GeckoFxTest/GeckoFxTest.csproj and GeckoFxTest/Main.cs to point to the right Firefox location. Everything is going fine. I can build and run it.

Problem happens when I tried to browse ANY webpage, for example google.com. After few second, browser window disappear and I saw this message in console:

My configuration: Ubuntu 11.10 on AMD, Mono 2.10.5, Mono develop 2.6, GeckoFX 7.0, 8.0 and 9.0 with appropriate xulrunner version.

```
###!!! ABORT: Main-thread-only object used off the main thread: file /home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/xpcom/base/nsCycleCollector.cpp, line 1267

###!!! ABORT: Main-thread-only object used off the main thread: file /home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/xpcom/base/nsCycleCollector.cpp, line 1267

Stacktrace:

Native stacktrace:

/usr/bin/mono() [0x80e126c]

/usr/bin/mono() [0x812046c]

/usr/bin/mono() [0x805fe7d]

[0xb77b040c]

/home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/obj-i686-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin/libmozalloc.so(_Z14mozalloc_abortPKc+0x3a) [0xb4156e00]

/home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/obj-i686-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin/libxul.so(NS_DebugBreak_P+0x45a) [0xb5272cd7]

/home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/obj-i686-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin/libxul.so(+0xcda825) [0xb5277825]

/home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/obj-i686-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin/libxul.so(+0xcdbfb4) [0xb5278fb4]

/home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/obj-i686-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin/libxul.so(NS_CycleCollectorForget2_P+0x2e) [0xb5279089]

/home/hvtuananh/Downloads/mozilla-release/obj-i686-pc-linux-gnu/dist/bin/libxul.so(+0x518973) [0xb4ab5973]

/usr/bin/mono() [0x8144ca4]

[0xb13a321a]

[0xb13a304c]

[0xb13a2f58]

/usr/bin/mono() [0x814fb27]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of two things:

You are using a 64bit version of firefox. geckofx doesn't yet support 64bit.

Or you need a newer mono which has this bug fix:
https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=672879

Comment: How do I know its 64? How do I know if the bug was fixed?

Comment: We have an app in beta that uses GeckoFX 29, on Ubuntu Precise and Trusty. So it's doable. https://github.com/BloomBooks/BloomDesktop